# CSS - How to handle position:absolute elements when resizing with media queries

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I'm currently writing media queries styling rules for a site I've built. The brief was such that I adopted a 'wide-first' stance and am now looking to ensure the site looks as it should on a mobile and/or tablet. 
A number of elements have been styled for the desktop using `position:absolute` and `position:relative` . This is now posing me significant problems when styling them for a smaller screen as they're behaviour when re-sizing is quite puzzling. Here's an example of what I mean -

```css
body {
  margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
}

.container {
  margin: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
}

section#home {
  height: 400px;
  background: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1496902526517-c0f2cb8fdb6a?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=85&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=srgb&dl=nik-macmillan-280300.jpg&s=b77cd43efa7b89864627fb18698457ca) center center no-repeat;
  background-size: 100%;
  background-position: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

#agencyimage {
  border: 1px solid red;
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0;
  top: 40%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.showreel {
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: black;
  bottom: 0;
  padding: 0 30px;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.showreel,
.showreel > div.seemore {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  flex: 1;
}

.showreel,
.showreel > div.seeour {
  justify-content: flex-end;
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.showreel p {
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: normal;
  margin: 0;
  padding-left: 10px;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.showreel i {
  color: #ffffff;
}

.seemore {
  margin-left: 30px;
}

.seeour i {
  margin-right: 30px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
  div.container {
    float: none;
    margin: 0 20px 0 20px;
  }
  div.column {
    float: none;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  body {
    max-width: 500px;
    border: 1px dashed #ccc;
    min-height: 400px;
  }
  section#home {
    float: none;
    height: 100%;
    background-size: 100%;
    position: static;
  }
  #agencyimage {
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
  }
  .showreel {
    position: relative;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<section id="home">

  <a href="agency.html"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" id="agencyimage" style="width: 150px; height: 250px;"></a>

  <div class="container showreel">
    <div class="seemore">
      <span class="fa-stack fa-lg">
                    <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x" style="color:#fff"></i>
                    <i class="fa fa-chevron-down fa-stack-1x" style="color: #000000;"></i>
                </span>
      <p>SEE MORE</p>
    </div>
    <div class="seeour">
      <p>SEE OUR SHOWREEL</p>
      <i class="fa fa-play-circle fa-3x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

And here's how the section looks after I re-size it down to 'mobile-size' -

[image: Mobile-size image]

The background-image does not re-size properly, its suppossed to be 400px in height and the centre image should still fit in the centre of the screen.
Do I need to completely re-style such elements for RWD? Are there specific rules to be aware of when positioning elements for a desktop then adjusting them for smaller screens?

Comment: You should be aware of inheritance in CSS and positioning of elements. Dig deeper into Relative and Absolute. Is it mobile first approach?

Comment: @VishalKumarSahu My question does state that it was a desktop-first approach. What do you mean by dig deeper?

Comment: as you can see, your code snippet does not replicate your layout. Please share all relevant code so you replicate your problem here. Otherwise we can not help you

Comment: @Mike.Whitehead You might want to host the images publicly, and update the urls to the images in the demo. That way we can actually see what you're talking about ;-)

Comment: @MihaiT How do I re-size a screen in a code snippet? All the relevant code is there.

Comment: that was not what i was talking about. i was talking about the styles. Your snippet does not look remotely the same as your posted image. ( No images , no icons etc. ) . You can include placeholder images and fontAwesome . Also please explain exactly what you don't like on mobile ( image, top round image , footer etc. ) .

Comment: @MihaiT How do i show a placeholder image on here?

Comment: @JohnSlegers Thanks, i've added a public url now for the back ground image.

Comment: @MihaiT Thanks, I've added a public url now for the background image.

Comment: @MihaiT I need the .showreel to span across the screen in tandem with the background image, i need the image size to be 400px height like at desktop size OR shrink down the agency image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give `background-size: cover;` to `section#home` for image to occupy complete height in lower resolutions and change container `css` as shown for the `showreel` to occupy complete width.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 480px){
section#home {
    float: none;
    height: 100%;
    background-size: cover;
    position: static;
}
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1000px){
div.container {
    float: none;
    margin: 0;
    width: calc(100% - 40px);
    right: 20px;
    left: 20px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
}
```

also if you don't want `agencyimage` to move to top below 480 resolution, then add this

```
@media screen and (max-width: 480px){
   #agencyimage {
       position: relative;
       transform: translate(-50%, 0%);
   }
}
```

Comment: The problem is I'm not getting the full height from the background image. How do I do that?

Comment: we couldn't see image in your snippet, you have given localhost path to the image which is not accessible to us.

Comment: you mean background image not occupying complete height ? then try giving background-size: cover;

Comment: I've just edited the question to include the public url for the background image, can you see it now?

Comment: This is great - thanks a lot. My .showreel black strip container doesn't stretch right across the screen - its short by about 5px on the left hand side - do I need to set a width rule for this?

Comment: I gave left:20px; right:20px; and width: calc(100% - 40px).
If want 5px more in the left then width should be calc(100% - 45px)